# Break string based on particular string match

Tags: regex, oracle, plsql, oracle10g

I have the following string in Oracle as one continuous line, where instead of displaying this information as one continuous string, I actually would like to append a carriage return/new line before ever occurrence of “:F” and “:L”, which would also require the removal of the “:” before F and L

So current string:

```
F:AA BB:F:BB CC dd:F:ZZ Xx Y:L:Hello:F:Goodbye
```

Newly displayed string:

```
F:AA BB
F:BB CC dd
F:ZZ Xx Y
L:Hello
F:Goodbye
```

Trying to achieve this as a concise function in Oracle pl/sql, so that I can pass in the current string and get back the new string with carriage return/new line breaks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think you need regex. The simple replace should do the trick.

```
new_val := REPLACE( REPLACE( string_val, ':F:', CHR(10)||'F:' )
                  , ':L:', CHR(10)||'L:' );
```

That gives unix style new lines. If you want windows newlines then you need to use `CHR(13)||CHR(10)` instead of just `CHR(10)`.

And you can use this just the same in a query too.

Comment: Perfecto @Sodved - I just had to add CHR(13)||CHR(10) for my requirement. Good work. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

And just to throw in a [regular expression replace](http://psoug.org/reference/regexp.html) way:

```
with TestData as(
select 'F:AA BB:F:BB CC dd:F:ZZ Xx Y:L:Hello:F:Goodbye' text from dual 
)

select testData.text , 
       REGEXP_REPLACE(testData.text, '(:)([F|L]+:)',CHR(13)||CHR(10) || '\2') REG_REP
  from testData

;
TEXT                                           REG_REP                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
---------------------------------------------- -----------
F:AA BB:F:BB CC dd:F:ZZ Xx Y:L:Hello:F:Goodbye F:AA BB                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
                                               F:BB CC dd                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
                                               F:ZZ Xx Y                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
                                               L:Hello                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
                                               F:Goodbye
```

---

```
 REGEXP_REPLACE(testData.text, '(:)([F|L]+:)',CHR(13)||CHR(10) || '\2')
```

the  () mark groupings that may be references in the replace by \GroupPosition#

```
(:)([F|L]+:)
```

pretty much is saying look for a  : followed by either F: or L:

```
CHR(13)||CHR(10) || '\2'
```

then replace the found text with "CHR(13)||CHR(10) ||" + the second group

Answer (score 0):

Using regexp:

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE('F:AA BB:F:BB CC dd:F:ZZ Xx Y:L:Hello:F:Goodbye',
                       (\:+)(F|L{1})(\:+)',
                       chr(13)||chr(10)||'\2\3')
from dual;
```

Is better match the pattern.